# How can I sort a map with a pair as a key in reverse order?

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, stl

I have a map

```
map< std::pair<double, long>, object > myMap;
```

basically I want it to sort by that pair.  How can I sort it so that my `double` is in descending order and my long is in ascending order.

so normally on insert I would get `({3.2, 5}, {3.2, 6}, {4, 1})` but what I want is to get `({4, 1}, {3.2, 5}, {3.2, 6})`.  I guess I could start thinking of my own algorithm but I was hoping there's a way to do this kind of how map lets you sort in reverse with `std::greater`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked  [at the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) ? (Hint hint: the template parameters)

Comment: Whats wrong with writing your own functor?

Comment: "instead of writing my own sorting algorithms" youre not writing an algorithm at all youre just writing a trivial comparison function. If you had use a distinct type instead of a pair id tell you to overload operator> which is AFAIK what std::greater calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no standard comparator that does what you want. Provide your own comparator which gives the order you want:

```
typedef std::pair<double, long> key; // for convenience

struct compare_keys {
    bool operator()(key const & lhs, key const & rhs) {
        if (lhs.first < rhs.first) return false;
        if (rhs.first < lhs.first) return true;
        return lhs.second < rhs.second;
    }
};
```

and use the third (optional) template parameter to specify this rather than `std::less`

```
std::map<key, object, compare_keys> myMap;
```

You can shorten (and arguably obfuscate) this slightly by comparing modified pairs:

```
return std::make_pair(-lhs.first, lhs.second) 
     < std::make_pair(-rhs.first, rhs.second);
```

Comment: I don't think the `tie` will work. `-lhs.first` isn't an lvalue.

Comment: oh nice negative of the key so that it's in reverse order.  I like it!